# Unable to submit for static analysis

Tags: sophoslabs-intelix

We are not able to submit file for static analysis

Tried with the request as below :

```
curl -X POST "https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1/"
-H "Authorization: <token>" 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "file=@<file_path>"
```

(As suggested in curl request text box)

Got Error as:

```
{"error":  "Not Found"}
```

As per the documentation this error means
The requested URL does not exist (Not Found).

But we are using the same URL as mentioned in Doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the curl command from text box at
https://api.labs.sophos.com/doc/analysis/file/static.html and ran it directly

It turned out that the suggested command in code block is having different URL that from list under Servers

In list server url is https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1 but in Curl we are getting https://de.api.labs.sophos.com/analysis/file/static/v1/(/ is appended) which in turn returns "Not Found" error

Tried after omitting / from URL and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Swagger's try it out feature, that generates the curl command, is currently unoperational, but you are right in that the endpoint should accept requests with the trailing slash in the URL.

Thank you for the bug report, we will fix this <strike>in the next patch, which can be expected to roll out before the end of next week.</strike> in a later release.